# How to read image from Application folder in winjs

Tags: winjs

### How to read image from Application folder in winjs

```
 var item = groupedProducts.getAt(indx);            
 item.img = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder.path + "\\" + "3766111.jpg";
                    groupedProducts.setAt(indx, item);
                    WinJS.UI.processAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the async APIs to access files in ApplicationData in WinJS, such as the getFileAsync function used below (this is a helper function I use in databinding for one of my apps):

```
function getLocalLargeMapTile(item) {
    return new WinJS.Promise(
        function (completed, error, progress) {
            var filename;
            var sourceFolder;

            if (item.latlong) {
                var latandlong = item.latlong.split(", ");
                var lat = latandlong[0];
                var lon = latandlong[1];
                filename = lat + lon + ".png";

                var appData = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current;
                sourceFolder = appData.localFolder;

                sourceFolder.getFileAsync(filename).then(function (file) {
                    var mapUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(file, { oneTimeOnly: true });
                    completed(mapUrl);
                },
                function (error) {
                    handleError(error)
                });
            }
            else {
                filename = "ms-appx:///images/megaphone_256x256.png";
                completed(filename);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

What I'm doing in the helper function is checking whether my data includes a latitude and longitude, and if so, checking for a file with a matching filename, and since those files are in the Application Data folder, wrapping the file with an objectURL and returning a promise with the objectURL. Otherwise, I simply return an ms-appx url pointing to a static file in the app's images folder. Here's how I call this helper function, from a programmatic template (I don't think you can do this with a declarative template):

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.className = "item-image";
image.src = "ms-appx:///images/megaphone_256x256.png";
result.appendChild(image);

// additional code omitted
var promise = mapTileUtil.getLocalMapTile(currentItem);
promise.done(function (mapTileUrl) {
    image.src = mapTileUrl;
});
```

For more info on templating functions, which provide greater control over the rendered markup than declarative templates, check out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj585523.aspx

and

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=231499

For more information on Windows Store app development in general, register for [App Builder](http://bit.ly/gd30tolaunch).

Comment: hi..i completed it partially.But my problem is my winJS listview update automatically when each download finish.But some images shows in unreadable form.why like this?

Comment: Run the project, and switch back to Visual Studio while the app is running and check the error list and output Window. If there's a problem with the images, you'll often get helpful messages in one of those places.